# Serverless Framework with localstack, where to view error output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless, localstack

I am using serverless framework along with localstack and getting a failed deploy with the error message

```
View the full error output: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A000000000000%3Astack%2Fpond5-api-local%2F00457845
```

That link will ask me to sign into AWS console... but i am running with localstack a mock environment, where can i get info about the failed deploy?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the link in the output directly points to AWS. I would suggest taking a look at the localstack logs as those will contain more detailed information about why the deployment failed. You can set `DEBUG=1` in the environment for troubleshooting issues.

Additionally, you can display more logs from the `serverless deploy` command by setting `SLS_DEBUG=*` in your environment (but those were often not very helpful for me)